# SQLite cumulative sum and WHERE containing SUBSTR()

Tags: database, sqlite

How do I get a cumulative sum based on the first character of column `code` for title records?

Consider:

```
 tbl_A:
 --------------------------------
 |  is_title  |  code  | amount |
 --------------------------------
 | true       | "1"    |      0 |
 | false      | "11"   |     10 |
 | false      | "12"   |     15 |
 | true       | "2"    |      0 |
 | false      | "21"   |     30 |
 | false      | "22"   |     40 |
 --------------------------------
```

I would like to get:

```
 -----------------------
 |  code  | cumulative |
 -----------------------
 | "1"    |         25 |
 | "2"    |         70 |
 -----------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to both `group by` and `select` the expression `substr(code,1,1)`.

```
select substr(code,1,1) as code, sum(amount) as cumulative
from tbl_A
group by substr(code,1,1)
```

Comment: thanks! Now, what about a more complex scenario like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519596/sqlite-cumulative-sum-and-where-containing-nested-substr