# SQLite cumulative sum and WHERE containing nested SUBSTR()

Tags: database, sqlite

How do I get a cumulative sum based on the code of title records?

Consider:

```
 tbl_A:
 --------------------------------
 |  is_title  |  code  | amount |
 --------------------------------
 | 1          | "1"    |   null |
 | 0          | "11"   |     10 |
 | 0          | "12"   |     15 |
 | 1          | "13"   |   null |
 | 0          | "131"  |      3 |
 | 0          | "132"  |      3 |
 | 1          | "2"    |   null |
 | 0          | "21"   |     30 |
 | 0          | "22"   |     40 |
 --------------------------------
```

I would like to get:

```
 --------------------------------
 |  code  | amount | cumulative |
 --------------------------------
 | "1"    |   null |         25 |
 | "11"   |     10 |       null |
 | "12"   |     15 |       null |
 | "13"   |   null |          6 |
 | "131"  |      3 |       null |
 | "132   |      3 |       null |
 | "2"    |   null |         70 |
 | "21"   |     30 |       null |
 | "22"   |     40 |       null |
 --------------------------------
```

My attempts are failing for aliasing a column on SELECT and using it on WHERE of a a nested SELECT.

Comment: I think you need to redesign your tables to not use special placeholder codes.

Comment: There is nothing cumulative in your example. Show your attempted queries.

Comment: Nevermind. It was getting too complicated for a query. I manipulated the data afterwards on an ArrayList.